# Heroku - Clone Laravel

Tags: laravel, heroku, laravel-5, heroku-toolbelt, gitkraken

I just have this problem today when I switched back to Windows 8.1 from Ubuntu 16.04.

So I was working this morning on Ubuntu and switched back to Windows for PS stuff. Once I finished, I opened my local repo for some modifications thru GitKraken but it won't stop loading the repo anymore - it's stuck up to the loading screen. So I went to terminal to check via `git log` and no logs anymore! As if it was a knew repository at all. To confirm that, I opened my Atom editor and all files are green :( - meaning they're not git'd yet.

Fortunately, yesterday, I pushed my work to Heroku. I just lost some hours because right after I pushed, I added more work especially on the CSS.

So I thought I should just clone my work from Heroku

`heroku git:clone -a my-app`

Then I opened my Laravel server
`php artisan serve` (no errors printed)

The errors says something related to vendors. So I issued `composer update`

But when I checked to browser for the home page it says "Whoops! Looks like something went wrong"

At this point I have no idea what to do. Any clues?

Comment: On your debug setting, and check actual error    'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),

Comment: Which one? the `.env` or from `app.php`?

Comment: If r u checking locally then .env else app.php

Comment: I'm checking locally but there's no `.env` anymore, why is that?

Comment: For setting.. then crate .env file

Comment: It's okay now, I've created one and set `.env`'s to debug mode. Thanks

Comment: When you clone your project then .env file is can't add in your project.. you need to crate it